# Toggle image within uicollectionviewcell when clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a uicollectionview with a series of custom class cells that have a few textviews and a uibutton. With over 100 cells, I just want to toggle  the uibutton image for each respective cell. The uibutton is a favorites button, and like most apps I just want to favorite and "un-favorite" different cells.

NOTE: I tried to add the gesture recognizer in the class directly, but for some reason the image changes, but it highlights multiple cells instead of the specific cell that was clicked

my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SimpleExampleSubCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.10, alpha: 0.25)
        cell.infoLine2TextVw.text = ""
        cell.infoLine3TextVw.text = ""
        if let heading_name = self.dict_dict_holder[indexPath.item]["Name"]{
            cell.headerTextVw.text = heading_name
            cell.infoLine1TextVw.text = self.dict_dict_holder[indexPath.item]["Phone"]
        }
        cell.bringSubview(toFront: cell.headerTextVw)
        cell.favorite_button.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddFavorite(withSender:))))
        return cell
    }


    @objc func AddFavorite(withSender sender:UIButton){
        print("clicked")
        //The line below fails each time I run it.
        sender.setImage(newImage.png,.normal)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
@objc func addFavorite(withSender sender:UIButton){
```

with

```
// not recommended use touchUpInside
@objc func addFavorite(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
  let btn = sender.view! as! UIButton
}
```

OR better

```
cell.favorite_button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(addFavorite), for: .touchUpInside)
```

> Don't Add tapgestures to buttons , as they they have their own targets like touchUpInside or touchUpOutside and many more
>
> table cells are reused you need to nil them inside cellForRowAt  or give an else

```
if someCondition { 
   cell.favorite_button.setImage(newImage1.png,.normal)
else { 
  cell.favorite_button.setImage(newImage2.png,.normal)
}
```

Comment: I changed my sender option to your suggestion, but I'm getting an unresolved identifier error when I try to write the line to set the image.

Comment: This definitely works, which is why I accepted it as the answer, however it seems to highlight that same cell's position's heart when ever I scroll up through my cells.

For example, I have 100+ cells, but there are only 4 cells viewable at a time. When I click on that first cell's button it changes as desired, but when I scroll up the first cell that shows in the view after scrolling now has a highlighted favorites button image. It changes as I scroll.

Comment: cells are reused you want to save the current state of every cell inside it's model

Comment: could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the default image (plus everything you want to reset) for each cell in the **prepareForReuse()** method so it clears up the reused content